# Nodejs how perform reduce() on array

Tags: node.js

I need to perform a reducer function on array.

My reducer function is `let rdx = function(a,b){return a*b}`

What is the best method in nodejs?

Comment: What have you tried? What documentation have you read on reduce (hint: [read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define an array called `yourarray` for example and write

```
var result = yourarray.reduce(rdx);
console.log(result);
```

Then execute and check on your console the result

Answer (score 2):

Here you a have an example of how to use reduce function in nodejs

```js
const array = [1,2,3,4,5];
const result = array.reduce((before, value, index) => {
  if (value < 3) {
    before.push(value);
  }
  return before;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

or you can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/) if you prefer and is like the same.